# Python and OpenCV: Resize image to square whie keeping the aspect ratio

Tags: python, opencv

I want to resize images but keep the aspect ratio with them (and also the white background).I'm working with Python and OpenCV. For example, I want my image like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjf8P.png) to become like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwFyI.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize an image without distortion OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44650888/resize-an-image-without-distortion-opencv)

Comment: you do not keep the aspect ratio of your image. Do you want to add a border or do you want to resize until the maximum size with original aspect ratio is reached and add border afterwards to fit the target size?

Answer (score 0):

You should go for 'making borders for images' section in this link [padding](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html) 
 Implement white border with hit and trial and you will get your desired aspect ratio